# AWS Cognito | OAuth 2 using Authorization Grant method | Issue with refresh token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are doing a POC to use AWS Cognito OAuth 2 Authorization Grant method. Using the Rest API method.

We are getting the set of access token and refresh token but when we refresh the token, we get a new set of access token and expiry but there is no refresh token. Hence we can refresh only once.

Hope to get some hints to solve this .

Comment: What happens if you use the refresh token again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUTHORIZATION Code Grant Flow never returns a Refresh Tokens, according to OAuth 2.0 standards. Repeating what the AWS [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) says on this:

> A refresh token is never returned in this flow.

If you would require a refresh token for your use-case, you would need to use the OAuth 2.0 compliant [TOKEN Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html).